# ToString(string format) в своем классе

Tags: c#, ооп

Как создать `public virtual string ToString(string format)` в своём классе, чтоб он отзывался, например, на `string.Format("{0:NNP}", x)`

мой метод

```
public virtual string ToString(string format)
{
  if (format == "NNP")
    return "NNP format";
  return ToString();
}
```

не вызывается при вышеупомянутом `string.Format("{0:NNP}", x)`, вместо него вызывается стандартный `public override string ToString()` класса. Как решить эту проблему

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Реализуйте интерфейс [IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Блин. Как всё просто =)